# Windows 8 uefi SSD

Tags: installation, boot, uefi

I have a new pc with a 128GB SSD, it has Windows 8 installed with UEFI.
It is a quadcore x4 amd chip.
I am attempting to install Kubuntu 13.10 64 on the machine via a USB powered DVD reader.

I followed various instructions I found on the site.  I can turn off via the boot menu (F2) the secure boot, I have also the options to choose UEFI OS or CSM OS or CSM & UEFI OS, I choose boot from DVD, but no matter what combination of options I choose, the DVD boots up, the Kubuntu image comes and glows and then a list of things zip past too fast to see.....and nothing else happens, the DVD is not accessed, nothing.

As I do not want Win 8 at all, could I use GParted and wipe out the disk and then install to a blank drive with the DVD or does UEFI do something else and things are locked down?

Thanks for any help.

Drew

Comment: Why not boot from a usb drive?

Comment: Did you go into Windows and in the power settings, turn off "fast boot"?  That is a vital first step.

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn off Intel smart response technolgy in BIOS? Secure boot need not be turned off, see here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI